# How can I solve Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions issue in .net framework 4.7?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8

I am getting this error while my webjob is starting to be ready in azure portal. I checked dlls and realized that only Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting is using "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" v 2.1.0

How can I solve this issue ? My project is .net framework 4.7 (please don`t forget this detail)

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

My csproj file :

```js
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <IsWebJobProject>true</IsWebJobProject>
    <WebJobName>$(AssemblyName)</WebJobName>
    <WebJobType>Continuous</WebJobType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="3.0.30" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="6.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" Version="3.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" Version="3.0.31" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.31" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="antlr.runtime">
      <HintPath>..\..\thirdparty\antlr-2.7.4\bin\antlr.runtime.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Org.Mentalis.Security">
      <HintPath>..\..\thirdparty\seclib-1.0\bin\Org.Mentalis.Security.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Sonic.Client">
      <HintPath>..\..\thirdparty\sonicmq-8.5.1\bin\Sonic.Client.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Sonic.Client.Jms.Impl">
      <HintPath>..\..\thirdparty\sonicmq-8.5.1\bin\Sonic.Client.Jms.Impl.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Sonic.Jms">
      <HintPath>..\..\thirdparty\sonicmq-8.5.1\bin\Sonic.Jms.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Sonic.Jms.Cf.Impl">
      <HintPath>..\..\thirdparty\sonicmq-8.5.1\bin\Sonic.Jms.Cf.Impl.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Sonic.Security">
      <HintPath>..\..\thirdparty\sonicmq-8.5.1\bin\Sonic.Security.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Settings.job">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I updated my csproj file like by adding:

```js
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="2.1.0" /> <!-- Add this line -->
```

but I got this error :

##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions from 2.1.1 to 2.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
let me update When I downgrade Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions from 6.0.0 to 2.1.1.

[image]

Comment: From your error message `Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions from 2.1.1 to 2.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.` it looks like you just need to use the Visual Studio Nuget package manager and use the `2.1.1` version of that package.

Comment: @Cleptus, I updated my qestion. There is a misunderstandig. I udded <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="2.1.0" /> but got second error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed the package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights` version `3.0.30`.

You can see that the below versions are included.

[image]

- Again, as mentioned in your `.csproj`, I have installed `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` version `3.0.31`.
- As `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` is already included and again we are referring the package new version.

[image]

The old version will be overridden with the new versions and the below settings related to `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions` are added in `web.config` file.

```cs
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.1.0" newVersion="2.1.1.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

- And in the `.csproj` the below settings are also included.

```cs
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.2.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
```

```cs
  <Content Include="packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.2.1.1\.signature.p7s" />
  <Content Include="packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.2.1.1\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.2.1.1.nupkg" />
```

- Your `.csproj` misses these references.

***Make sure you to add the above tags in your `Web.config` and `.csproj` file to avoid the conflicts with the versions.***

> ```cs
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
> ```

Thanks @Cleptus for the comment.

From the Comment I understood that you have updated the package directly in the `.csproj` file.

Yes, as suggested in the error message, instead of updating directly in the `.csproj` , update the package version from the NuGet package.

***OR***

Delete the existing package completely, build the application and install the required package again.

Comment: This is error in my pipeline:  ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions from 6.0.0 to 2.1.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.

Comment: But this is a console app : The old version will be overridden with the new versions and the below settings related to Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions are added in web.config file.

 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.1.0" newVersion="2.1.1.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>

Comment: Ok .. will look into it and let you know.

Comment: `.csproj` file for console app starts with [<?xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzW7R.png).But I see your `.csproj` like [Core App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iTDg.png).